# Folded Normal and truncated Normal

Tags: normal-distribution, truncation

Suppose to have a vector of random variables $\mathbf{y}$, distributed as a multivariate normal with mean vector $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$.

The variable $\mathbf{Z} = | \mathbf{Y} |$ (where the modulo operator is applied to each component of $\mathbf{Y}$) is distributed as a folded normal.

If we set $\boldsymbol{\mu}= \mathbf{0}$, then is $\mathbf{Z}$ distributed as a multivariate truncated normal, with left truncation  at $\mathbf{0}$?

Comment: For some analyses of data from folded Normal distributions, please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117935/correlation-estimation-on-half-normal-distribution.  I think a quick look at some of these data will make the answer to this question perfectly obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the univariate case, when we truncate a **zero-mean** normal at zero (which is the same as taking its absolute value), then the folded-normal and the truncated normal family share a common member, the half-normal.

This is not in general the case in a multivariate setting. Treating the bivariate case, let's see under which conditions the identity nevertheless holds.

The density of the bivariate half normal can be compactly written (adjusting the formulas that can be found [here](http://www.stat-athens.aueb.gr/~jpan/papers/Panaretos-ApplStatScience2001(119-136)ft.pdf) ) as

$$f_H(x,y)=4\frac{\sqrt {1-\rho^2}}{s_xs_y}\cdot\phi(x/s_x)\cdot\phi(y/s_y)\cdot\text{cosh}\left(\frac{\rho xy}{s_xs_y}\right)$$

with

$$s_x = \sigma_x\sqrt {1-\rho^2}, \,s_y = \sigma_y\sqrt {1-\rho^2}$$

and where $\phi()$ is the standard normal PDF and $\text{cosh}$ is the hyperbolic cosine function.

The density of the bivariate normal truncated from below at zero is

$$f_T(x,y) = \left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac {1}{\sigma_x}\phi(x/\sigma_x)\Phi\left(\frac {\rho}{\sqrt {1-\rho^2}}\frac {x}{\sigma_x}\right)dx\right]^{-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt {1-\rho^2}}{s_xs_y}\times\\\times\; \phi(x/s_x)\cdot\phi(y/s_y)\cdot \exp\left\{-\frac{\rho xy}{s_xs_y}\right\}$$

Note that multiplying and dividing the integral in the expression by $2$ we obtain

$$\Big[...\Big] = \frac 12-\frac 12 G\left(0;0,\sigma_x,\frac {\rho}{\sqrt {1-\rho^2}}\right)$$

where $G(x;\text{location},\text{scale}, \text{skew})$ is the Skew Normal CDF, for which we have (see for example [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11123-014-0389-8) eq. $(18)$)

$$G\left(0;0,\sigma_x,\frac {\rho}{\sqrt {1-\rho^2}}\right) = 2B(0;0;-\rho)$$

where $B()$ is the bivariate standard normal integral. This relation verifies that the integral can equivalently be written in terms of the $y$ variable without imposing equality of variances between $x$ and $y$ -the variance term does not affect its value.

Then, if $\rho =0$, one can verify that the two densities become identical: the reciprocal of the integral equals $4$ and the other generally non-equal terms all become unity, giving

$$\rho =0 \Rightarrow f_H(x,y) = f_T(x,y) = \frac{4}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}\cdot\phi(x/\sigma_x)\cdot\phi(y/\sigma_y)$$

**So it appears that the condition needed for the identity of the densities to hold is that the two underlying zero-mean normals are independent, but not in addition that they have the same variance.**

**Opportunity taken**, [Horrace 2005](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X04002167) collects many useful results related to multivariate truncated normal distributions. Perhaps the most interesting is the following:

> If $\mathbf w$ is a multivariate truncated normal, then the linear
>   combination $\mathbf y = \mathbf D\mathbf w+\mathbf b$ is *not*
>   multivariate truncated normal, excpet if $\mathbf D = \mathbf I$.

In other words, with truncation present, normality is preserved under shifting but not under scaling.

Also,

> If $\mathbf w$ is a multivariate truncated normal vector of **correlated**
>   random variables, then the marginal distributions are not, in general,
>   truncated normal, but the conditional distributions are truncated
>   normal. If the variables are independent, then the marginal distributions also are truncated normals.

Finally, **log-concavity** and the multivariate generalization of **unimodality** characterize the multivariate truncated normal.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are wrong. In a bivariate case, the density of $(x,y)$ is $4\phi_2(z|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)$ for the truncated normal ($\phi_2(x,y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)$ is the bivariate normal pdf with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$) while is $\phi_2(x,y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)+\phi_2(-x,y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)+\phi_2(x,-y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)+\phi_2(-x,-y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)$ for the bivariate half normal. The two are identical if the correlation is 0, i.e $\phi_2(x,y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)=\phi_2(-x,y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)=\phi_2(x,-y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)=\phi_2(-x,-y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)$

Comment: @niandra82 Thanks for the input. I am checking this out.

Comment: Im pretty sure, but please let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: @niandra82 An intermediate question: you obtain the density of the truncated bivariate normal $4\phi_2(x,y|\mathbf{0}, \Sigma)$, under an assumption of independence between the two variables? Because I cannot see how else the normalizing factor would equal $4$.

Comment: Ok, in this case you are right, I made a mistake.

Comment: @niandra82 I find that you are right regarding the general conclusion "not the same distribution", but you are wrong regarding the conditions for obtaining the identity: it appears that we need only independence and not also identical variances. I reworked my post accordingly, including the calculations. Let's hope there are no mistakes left.

Comment: You are again right

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos As for this paper: https://www.proquest.com/docview/2670457270?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true (see corollary 1) a linear combination of truncated multivariate normal distribution is a truncated normal distribution as long as the scaling matrix is positive definite.

Comment: @shani Thanks, will look into it.