# Sampling from multivariate normal and folding to draw correlated half-normal samples

Tags: sampling

I'm trying to draw samples from a bivariate half-normal distribution whose variances and covariances I want to specify. I tried using scipy.stats, but it only offers a univariate half-normal.

My initial approach using the scipy package has been to use a multivariate normal and take the absolute value of the results.

Since the half-normal variance is $\sigma^2 (1 - \frac{2}{\pi})$, I can use a multivariate normal with an adjusted variance. E.g. if I want my half-normal variance to equal $v$, draw from the multivariate normal with a variance of $\frac{v}{1 - \frac{2}{\pi}}$.

I can verify that this achieves the desired result in scipy:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

hn_var = 3
hn_cov = 0
scaled_var = hn_var / (1 - (2 / np.pi))

x = multivariate_normal.rvs(
    mean=[0, 0],
    cov=[[scaled_var, hn_cov],
         [hn_cov, scaled_var]],
    size=(10000000, 1)
)
x = np.abs(x)
```

```
In [3]: np.var(x, axis=0).round(2)                                                                                                       
Out[3]: array([3., 3.])
```

The issue is that I'm struggling to specify the desired covariances.

If I change hn_cov to anything other than 0, the resulting covariance won't match due to the folding of the multivariate normal at 0.

How can I alter the multivariate normal covariance prior to folding at 0 to achieve the desired covariance?

Comment: Could you please tell us *which* bivariate half-normal distribution you have in mind?  This requires providing a quantitative description of the joint distribution.

Comment: @whuber I didn't realize there were multiple bivariate half-normal distributions. Specifically, I'm interested in the joint PDF specified for the half-normal in the accepted answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121747/folded-normal-and-truncated-normal